# Unable to add a document to Firebase

Tags: angular, firebase, angularfire

Has anyone faced such an issue, when you have assigned a reference to a document in Firebase (which is not there yet, it's only a place), then put a literal object there and it's not appearing?

**interacting-with-firebase.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { from, Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
import { User } from '../../classes/user';
import { AngularFireAuth } from 'angularfire2/auth';
import { AngularFirestore} from 'angularfire2/firestore';
import { switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

public signup(name: string, surname: string, email: string, password: string, photoUrl: string): Observable<boolean> {
    return from(this.angularFireAuth.auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then(userCredentials=> {
      const dieBenutzerreferenz = this.angularFirestore.doc(`chatUsers/${userCredentials.user.uid}`);
      const updatedUser = {
        id: userCredentials.user.uid,
        email: userCredentials.user.email,
        name,
        surname,
        photoUrl
      };
      dieBenutzerreferenz.set(updatedUser);
      return true;
    }).catch(
      (error) => false
    ));
  } // end of signup(){}
```

I've been working on it since yesterday, unfortunately I don't have anyone to consult it with (I build the first applications myself) and my eyes are red. Thank you.
I still use AngularFire2, but regardless, until recently it worked for me, now it doesn't.

I will add the user class structure if that would be of help.

**user.ts**

```
export class User {
    id: string;
    email: string;
    name: string;
    surname: string;
    photoUrl: string;

    constructor({id, email, name, surname, photoUrl}) {
        this.id = id;
        this.email = email;
        this.name = name;
        this.surname = surname;
        this.photoUrl = photoUrl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The method `set` is an `async` function, therefore you need to either `await` it or wait for the promise.